# Исполняемый файл не находит файлы по относительному пути mac os

Tags: c++, xcode

Проблема заключается в следующем:
Допустим, у меня есть исполняемый файл unix:
*/Users/username/Desktop/myAppFolder/myApp*
И есть документ, который нужен для работы приложения:
*/Users/username/Desktop/myAppFolder/shader.glsl*

В исходниках я использовал относительный путь *shader.glsl*, то есть файл лежит в папке, выбранной рабочим каталогом Xcode. Это означает, что исполняемый файл myApp должен искать shader.glsl в той же директории, где находится сам, но только в теории. Если перед компиляцией прописать абсолютный путь, shader.glsl находится. Если запускать проект в Xcode, файл shader.glsl так же находится. Но если отыскать исполняемый файл myApp в файлах Xcode в папке DerivedData и запустить, даже не перемещая его оттуда, он не может найти shader.glsl. Если переместить его в одну папку с shader.glsl, проблему это не решает.
Куда мне нужно положить shader.glsl чтобы myApp его нашел? Почему myApp не находит shader.glsl, если они лежат в одной директории? Может, в Xcode нужно как-то указывать файлы, с которыми работает приложение?

Comment: Относительный путь, это путь *относительно директории* откуда вы **запускаете** свою программу, а не относительно директории, где эта программа лежит.

Comment: Относительный путь - путь относительно *текущей* папки, а не относительно той, где находится исполняемый файл.

Comment: @user7860670 извините за непонимание, но что является текущей директорией в моём случае? Папка моего пользователя? Терминал её открывает если ввести "open ." Мне нужно как то менять эту директорию при запуске приложения?

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/current_path

Comment: Текущая папка определяется способом запуска приложения и тем, что оно делает после запуска. В этом случае скорее имеет смыл использовать абсолютный путь. Его можно сформировать, получив абсолютный путь до исполняемого файла.

Comment: @user7860670 какой самый простой универсальный способ узнать путь до исполняемого файла?

Comment: Никаких простых и универсальных способов нет, есть только кривые и платформо-специфические.

Comment: @user7860670 работа с документами реализована в любом приложении, которое содержит какие либо файлы, кроме исполняемого, то есть практически во всех. Там тоже используется этот метод?

Comment: Конечно. Если приложение должно работать с какими-то файлами, лежащими рядом с исполняемым, то оно первым делом должно определять абсолютный путь до папки, где находится исполняемый файл.

Comment: @MaksimMaltsev Самый простой способ узнать путь исполняемого файла - в методе main есть массив argv (может быть немного другое название). Путь самого исполняемого файла - первый его элемент, argv[0]. Вам осталось убрать из пути имя самого исполняемого файла, и подставить имя вашего файла данных.